# TabItem Header Click not Always Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I wanted to find a method of firing an event when the TabItem of a Page is selected. I had a look around and found that placing a Label on the header and using `MouseLeftButtonDown` was a way of making this event fire. The XAML looks like this;

```
    <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Label Content="Archived Jobs"  MouseLeftButtonDown="CallArchivedJobsTabItemSelected"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
```

There is an issue with this fix though, in that if the user clicks in a specific place under the `Label` they will be able to select the `TabItem` without the event firing. How can I program this differently to ensure that they cannot bypass the event firing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use [SelectionChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.selectionchanged(v=vs.95).aspx), it works pretty well. See example:

```
private void MyTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You selected tab number {0}", MyTabControl.SelectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all well for me. Lots of freezing of the UI and doesn't always fire either.

Comment: Would you please post the code that is executed when the event is fired, so we can take a look? It worked just fine here.

Comment: I want to execute code based on which of four `TabItems` are selected. Unfortunately after doing that it freezes up the `DataGrids` on each `TabItem` and I can't select them. I'll do something like `if(tab1.IsSelected){ // do something } if(tab2.IsSelected).....`

Comment: After doing that I cannot select any item on my `DataGrid`

Comment: You're using a TabControl, right? Perhaps it is the kind of stuff you're doing inside those ifs that freezes the UI? Highly recommend that you edit your question and put all your code in it

Comment: But when I use the `MouseLeftButtonDown` on the `Label` I have no problems with the stuff inside the ifs. I would post the code but it's quite a lot and irrelevant really to this question. I also get this error when using `SelectionChanged` : `Dispatcher processing has been suspended, but messages are still being processed.`

Comment: As far as I know this error is thrown when the thread that was processing the messages is suspended to avoid bugs when another thread (usually the UI) its about to do something, but I'm not pretty sure, you might wanna google it. But based on your previous answers and assuming that I'm right about the error, I think you're trying to do something on the interface, so perhaps you should use **Dispatcher.BeginInvoke** method where the exception was thrown  (?).

Comment: You were 100% right, I was refreshing the `ItemsSource` of the DataGrid and it was freezing up, thanks for your help.